# Particle Tracing

Tags: particles, animation-nodes, path, sverchok

I'm trying to trace a particle system but I haven't had luck.
The options i'I've tried are:

1. Path: Under the render tab in the particle system.

But it needs a keyed particle system and when I use a keyed system, it doesn't behave the way I want.

2. bTrace: https://vimeo.com/192873201

But it Works only with a small amount of particles. It takes ~10 min to trace the path of 20  particles and I need at least 100 particles.

3. AN & SV: In YouTube -> [BLENDERSUSHI / ANSV Particle Tracing Revisited](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOE0rFcMb8c)

I made the same node setup and it does not work and when I use the .blend that Jimmy Gunawan provides, I get some weird results:

[image]

I don't know any more options to get the result. Maybe liquid? other add-on? maybe I made the node setup wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: bTrace would ahve been my first option too. Otherwise have you looked into addons like Animation Nodes, or Sverchock? Not sure they do tracing but might be worth a shot investigating

Comment: Hello, yes. That was my last option but it has some weird results. I'll try to investigate again.

Comment: @Pierre Puentes, if you want help with particle tracing, i suggest supplying an example .blend of a particle system that does the things you want. it's easier for me to then show you have to trace the particles using Sverchok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store particle locations in a list?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105090/how-to-store-particle-locations-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

diggin old thread, but.. the path option doesnt need a keyed particle system, but keyframes, so you need to bake your simulation to cache. 
see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWOAuA6nqJc