# How to store particle locations in a list?

Tags: animation, node-editor, particles, animation-nodes

my question is how to store the locations of a particle or any changing data in a list so as to use the locations for effects like trails.

What I intend to create are particle trails, the following steps come to mind:
1. Get the locations of a particle through a loop node(so that the subsequent steps can be applied to other particles).
2. Use the stored locations to make splines.
3. Make the splines only have a definite length over the period they are present, that means they can only be created from say the last 3 stored locations at any given time.

This is the theory of how I plan to do it, in fact I have tried, but I could not find a way to store constantly changing values.

Also I would like to know a way to store the location of the particle for each frame or any arbitrary number of frames so as to be able to control the smoothness of the splines.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no intuitive way to do this in Animation Nodes. I proposed a system to the developer that should hopefully allow us to do this intuitively. But he is still studying it. In the meantime, I will tell you how to make such system manually.

---

## Storing Data

Each execution in Animation Nodes is independent of the next one, and thus we can't pass data between executions. To solve this, we need store the data in some place accessible by all executions at all times, a typical solution is to store the data in-memory, somewhere in the `animation_nodes` or `bpy` modules for instance. In python, to store some data `data` in the `animation_nodes` module in an attribute called `test`, we can use the `setattr()` built-in method as follows:

```
setattr(animation_nodes, "test", data)
```

If you are still not sure how this work, you can think of it as follows. We are storing the data `data` in a place in memory called `animation_nodes.test`, we can later access this data simply by getting it from the place we stored it in, that is, `animation_nodes.test`. Enough about this, lets talk practicality.

## Implementation

What I shall show is tracing the location of the particles in a form of splines. First, we are going to compute what is known as the *initial condition*, which is the initial state of the system. In our case, the initial condition is a list of empty splines. We can generate it using the *Fill List Node* set to *Spline* type, where the amount of empty splines is equal to the number of particles (make sure not to filter the particles in anyway, because we want to maintain the number of particles):

[image: Initial Condition]

What are going to do is append the particles locations to each of those splines at each frame (execution). In an expression node, I am going to input the initial conditions and set this expression:

```
initial if bpy.data.scenes[0].frame_current == 1 else animation_nodes.splines
```

Basically, this returns `initial` which is the initial condition (list of empty splines) if the frame is equal to one and `animation_nodes.splines` (some data we are going to set later on) otherwise. Why did we do this step? We are merely resetting the splines to be empty (to be the initial condition) when the frames becomes one, that is, when the time line resets, and that is what we want, we want the animation to reset when the animation resets. Now, I am going to make a loop that appends the current particles positions to their corresponding splines:

[image: Append Points]

And lastly, I am going to assign/reassign the data at the memory location `animation_nodes.splines` to be the new data after appending using the `setattr()` method we described before:

[image: Reassign]

Lets recap what is happening here. At frame 1, the input to the loop are empty splines, the output of the loop is splines with a single point that has the location of the particles, this output is assigned to the memory location `animation_nodes.splines`. At frame 2, the input to the loop is the data at `animation_nodes.splines`, that is, the splines with a single vertex that has the location of the particles at frame 1, the output is splines that has two vertices, the first is that of locations of the particles at frame 1 and the second is that of the locations of the particles at frame 2, this new splines are assigned to `animation_nodes.splines`. So, you see that at each new frame, the splines get a new point that is the location of the particle at this frame. The result is growing splines as the time passes:

[image: Result]

The structure we just used can be edited appropriately to suite your needs, and it nearly stays the same, get data, edit it, reassign it, repeat.

Comment: Thanks Omar, this is what I needed, although I do not know how to program, I will try my best to understand and implement this technique. Thank you once again!

Comment: Thanks Dembos for the great question and Omar for the brillant answer ! It's very handy for scientific visualization.

Comment: If you want to avoid rapidly growing lists, you can rig up [something like this](https://i.imgur.com/eQSWrii.png) in the Append Points loop. Probably a neater way to do it, but it allows the list to grow to a certain length then starts stripping off elements.

Comment: @Different55 I think using a switch node between the original and appended spline using inforced copying should be more efficient.

Comment: Hm... not sure I follow what you mean there.

Comment: @Different55 Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkLgX.png). The condition should be something like the alive status of the particles.

Comment: @OmarAhmad Ah gotcha. By infinitely growing I meant more that each particle's history is remembered forever. The setup I have only stores the last X locations for each particle.

Comment: be shure to uncheck "random order" in particle settings

Comment: _I proposed a system to the developer that should hopefully allow us to do this intuitively. But he is still studying it._ – Can you post a link to the discussion?