# Save value on first occurrence in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

In this setup *Random number* defines Y position of *Empty*, which is *shrinkwrapped-constrained* to "Array of stairs".

I'd like to save Z value (orange circle) in memory, when the first positive number will be generated (green circle) and keep it until animation ends.
And please, do not modify *Random number* node.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:** I've added another `attribute` to workaround saving value from previous frame. Looks messy, but works.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes can be stored in memory during the life time of the blender instance as described in this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105090/how-to-store-particle-locations-in-a-list). In this particular case, the logic is as follows. We have two variables `occurred`, `storedValue`:

- If the current frame is equal to the start frame, reset `storedValue` to some initial value and reset `occurred` to False.
- If trigger value is positive:

  - If `occured` is False:

    - Set `storedValue` to the value.
  - Set `occurred` to True.

Comment: Thanks, part of the job is done - I can keep value https://imgur.com/a/zTQ3cFI But as expected it getting overwritten once there is another positive number in next frames

Comment: @SergeL You also need to check if the variable already stored is positive, if it is positive, then you shouldn't change it. So you should do `x > 0` as well and factor that. Makes sense?

Comment: I don't understand why X>0, if it is just "Z loc" and can be any number? I added condition that forces X to be written only when attribute is empty and it solves "rewrite problem", except it saves wrong value (on previous frame, not current) https://imgur.com/a/FZCe8zm

Comment: @SergeL Sorry, my bad. I updated the answer.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without depending on frame numbers? I need to do something similar, but not necessarily animated.