# how do i store a value when using animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

I am translating a list of objects but I only want the translation in the x,y,z plane to occur during frame one then after frame one the translation to happen only in the x,y plane.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105090/how-to-store-particle-locations-in-a-list and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128215/save-value-on-first-occurrence-in-animation-nodes/128220#128220

Comment: You want the z location to be set to zero after frame 1?

Comment: Thank you for the response those links look like they would work but may be over my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to create the numbers that I needed. I created a line of vertices that were in the z range that I wanted, then made sure the vert count was equal to my particle count. I then iterated the vert locations through the loop and separated the z values and reinserted them into the translation data. Thank you for all the help and suggestions. They looked viable just a lot more complicated.

Comment: I guess you do not need to make sure the vert count is equal to the particle count, loops will only iterate through the shortest list. I just need to make sure the vert count is >= the particle count