# Transfer data between nodetrees in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I'd like to split one network into subprocess' and assign them to specific *Nodetrees*. General idea is to have `Custom Execution Trigger` on every subprocess to improve overall performance.

But how to transfer values between trees?

I can write/read values in *Object ID properties*, but they has limited use case, throwing error for Meshlist/Splines:

> only floats, ints and dicts are allowed in ID property arrays

Also what is this interesting button *Go to parent nodetree* (green highlight)?:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just store/get data from any node tree in memory as described in this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105090/how-to-store-particle-locations-in-a-list). Alternatively, you can use the *Data Interface* node to pass data between node trees.

In a node tree, you can export some data using the *Data Interface* node, then, in another node tree, you can access that data by referencing the node tree name and the *Data Interface* node name using the following expression:

```py
bpy.data.node_groups[nodeTreeName].nodes[nodeName].value
```

Where `nodeTreeName` is your node tree name and `nodeName` is the *Data Interface* node name. Here is an example:

[image: Node Tree]

As for the *Go to parent nodetree* operator, this has nothing to do with Animation Nodes. It is a native operator that allows one to exit a node group when using cycles or the compositor (Pressing Tab).