# Animation Nodes -> splines generated and how have a random material color for each spline?

Tags: materials, animation-nodes, splines

following 
[How to store particle locations in a list?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105090/how-to-store-particle-locations-in-a-list/163157)

you can trace particles to splines (list), but

how can we have a random color in the material for each of the splines...

they are all in one object so Object Info -> Random doesn't work,

I don't wanne to copy/split this afterwards...

maybe/I think the animation nodes tree can expanded somehow, but I a too noob with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods:

1. In blender 2.82, In geometry node there is a socket "**random per island**", that will generate color for separated meshes within the same object. **Be aware, currently this socket can only work for cycles**, not possible in eevee.
   [image]
2. while using "curve object output" node, it's preferred in a loop, and input an object list. Since you are making them multiple objects, you can use "object info - random". **This method allows you work in eevee, and transform different splines separately**.
   [image]
   Must a method over the other? I don't think so.

**Edit:** 
Specifically in particle tracing, it's exactly the same principle. You are outputing multiple splines, before you curve object output anything, simply generate a loop that input iterators of object list and spline list. and it will solve the problem.
[image]

Comment: okay I see, but, can the traced particle splines like it the orignal post, be transformed into individual splines !?

Comment: It's the same principle. In particle tracing, you are outputing multiple splines. generate a loop that has iterators of object list and spline list. and output curve within the loop, will solve this problem. If you are still not clear, see the edit of this post.

Comment: wow - AN is getting more clear to me now !