# Assemble / Disintegrate with Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I would like to assemble an object made of Polys but I get stuck because the integration does
not stay.

At the moment I use the Offset Polygons Node to set the scale of the Polys influenced by a
locator object and a Point Distance Falloff as seen in the image.
[image]
[image]
I can reverse the falloff by an invert node that gives me what I want, but because its a
Point Falloff it does not stay,.

the directional Falloff is close to what I want but I would like to have it starting from
a point and not going in a fixed direction. directional Falloff is way to "directional"
[image]
the main goal at the end is injecting the object at different points and let the scale "grow"
till comlete visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to store previous state of falloff. This allows to stay effect of falloff even it is changed.

In this example it stores `Maximum` falloff of `Object Controller Falloff` on each execution. The values of falloff are stored in `AN.falloffData`. The value of falloff is reset when frame is 1. The working of this technique is well explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105090/how-to-store-particle-locations-in-a-list)

To store data to AN module : `setattr(AN, "falloffData", x)`

Access stored data : `AN.falloffData`

[image]

[image]