# Follow objects as if there was a magnetic field using animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

Using animation nodes how can I make an object keep following and other object with some delay, a behavior very similar to the one you can see in most paint tools for stabilizing strokes, here is an example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ah13EISw7nc

The only difference is that at the end of the transform both objects should have same location.

EDIT

here a perfect example of what I'm trying to reproduce, but without "actions"
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0c4TvpGl_A)

Comment: Isn't that, that it is necessary to hold shift, while drawing, to have this "magnetic effect"?

Comment: For the example provided could be, but I am not trying to reproduce de stabilizer function, I shared the link in order to show how objects should behave. The idea is to move an object and this other object should follow the first one with a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1** (Recommended)

You can evaluate Fcurves to get trailing or attractive effect. You need a source object with location keyframes. Then follow node tree given below.
[image]

[image]

**Method 2**

We can also do this without keyframed source object by [storing positions of object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105090/how-to-store-particle-locations-in-a-list).
[image]
For storing object transformation as Matrixlist:

`setattr(AN, "store", Matrix4x4List()) if frame == 1 else AN.store.append(x)`

Get stored Matrixlist:

`AN.store[-amount:]`

[image]