# Animation Nodes: Loop - get value from previous iteration (ie, rotation of previous object in the list)

Tags: animation-nodes

I have a list of objects going into a loop.

Inside the loop, I am modifying each object's location. Each object has rotation keyframes, which is driving my AN.

However, I would like to modify its location based on the rotation of the *previous* object in the list. That is to say, the previous iteration.

Is this possible? If so, what's the best way forward?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, 

I thought ID Key: Index would be the answer, but sadly I can't find a way to select objects from the scene based on ID Key. 

Is there a node I can use within a loop to pick an object based on its ID Key? 

ie, I have 10 cubes, with ID keys set, ranging from 0-9. 

I'd like to grab the Transform date from the object with ID Key Index that is one lower than the current index of the loop - in an attempt to reference the previous object in the loop.

Comment: Can u show your node tree or upload blend file, may be there is easier way to do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store particle locations in a list?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105090/how-to-store-particle-locations-in-a-list)